# The rule to enable the button does not work if the keyboard is active

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a rule to enable or disable a button. The rule works, but when the keyboard is enabled, it doesn't.

Is there any button property that can be used to solve this?

```
             Observer(
             builder: (_) =>  Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: TrinusButton(
                  isEnabled: controller.getActveButton(),
                  text: 'next'.toLowerCase(),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (controller.type.toString() == 'email') {
                        Modular.to.pushNamed('/route...');
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  fontColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
           );
```

Controller

```
  @observable
  bool activeButtomNewChave = false;
  
  @action
  bool getActveButton() {
    return activeButtomNewChave;
  }
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze this!

Comment: when did you create the controller? FYI, if you are using Scaffold, or any widgets that depends on the MediaQuery, when the soft keyboard is shown or hidden, it will rebuild the widget. So, pay attention on when you create the Controller.

Comment: I created a custom component that has Scafold. This component is used throughout the project. Is there any possibility to solve this problem without having to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `MobX`? If you want to get one value, you need to wrap the widget with `Observer` and avoid using an `@action` to access this value.

```dart
Observer(
  builder: (_) =>  Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: TrinusButton(
                  isEnabled: controller.activeButtomNewChave,
                  text: 'next'.toLowerCase(),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (controller.type.toString() == 'email') {
                        Modular.to.pushNamed('/route...');
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  fontColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              );
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made the changes, however, the button is only enabled when I close the keyboard.